# How to handle next/previous of fullCalendar in reactjs

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, reactjs

REQUIREMENT: I need to show the events which are displayed on the calendar in the sidebar component as a summary. 
I'm displaying the fullCalendar using `ReactJS` like this

```
var Calendar = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
 return {
   attendances: []
 }
},
fetchEvents: function() {
 this.setState({
   attendances: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents')
 });
},
componentDidMount: function() {
 var calendar = new App.Calendar($('#calendar'));
 calendar.render(calendar);
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', '/dashboard/attendances');
 setTimeout(this.fetchEvents, 1000);
},
render: function(){
 return (
   <div>
     <p>{this.state.attendances}</p>
   </div>
 )
}
});

React.render(<Calendar />, document.getElementById('calendar'));
```

As you can see i'm fetching the events using `addEventSource` to publish them on the calendar and later on using `clientEvents` to fetch the rendered events on the calendar. But obviously this won't work for the `next` and `prev` buttons. I tried `componentWillUpdate` if this methods gets trigger or not but no luck so far. Any ideas on this ?

Comment: How did you make fullcalendar works with react?